# Taxonomy Access Control

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm creating a site which will have multiple 'store' sections, with each store's staff needing to edit their own content, but not anyone else's.

The eventual layout will look something like this.

- Store One

  - Page A
  - Page B
- Store Two

  - Page C
  - Page D

This is fine - I figure I should have a vocabulary for 'Stores' and a term for each Store, and then use an access control module to limit page editing based on term.

Now, the complexity: we also need a certain amount of custom information displayed on the front page for each store (think opening hours, location etc). I figure the best place way to achieve this is to have a set of custom fields for each term, and then display them in a view that also lists the pages for the store.

**Thus the problem:** How do I allow a store to edit their term (and it's custom fields) but not others?

Will gratefully receive to any and all potential solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar use case on my site.  I ended up making stores a content type for that very reason.  Entity reference is your friend cause you can create page a and b and link em to the store content entity.

Comment: Yeah I might have to go down that path - trying to teach users how to edit a taxonomy term is probably a bridge too far. Entity Reference certainly looks good!

Comment: It really does add a new wrinkle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like the Workbench suite of modules. The Workbench Access module allows you to only allow certain users to edit sections of your website, so you could set the permission at the store level and it would cascade down to all of the pages associated with the store. It works well with taxonomies.

https://drupal.org/project/workbench

Comment: Thanks - Workbench Access is great, except it doesn't solve my particular issue of wanting to apply access control to a taxonomy as well as general content types.

Comment: If you look in the settings, you can use a taxonomy to enforce access control for taxonomies. "The module supports Taxonomy and Menu modules for the management of access hierarchies."

So it seems to fit with your statement: "vocabulary for 'Stores' and a term for each Store, and then use an access control module to limit page editing based on term"

You then put each user/role as an editor under each term for granular editing access. When you add content, you tag the appropriate section. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are asking for?